# Killing one child proc after the other dies

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to create 2 processes - one fast and one slow (though in my actual case, I wouldn't know which is what). I want that after the fast dies, the slow will die too, without completing its function.

*Adding `join()` is problematic, because in my actual case I don't know which one is the fast and `join()`-ing both of them will wait for the slower... Also, adding a `time.sleep()` is also problematic because I don't know how much time my actual fast process will take...*

Is there a way to make the father process aware to both child-processes , and kill the one, if the other died? (Thought of adding a while-loop, checking `is_alive()` for both processes every second, but that seems both weird and bad because I won't know where to `join()` them...

```
    In [1]: import multiprocessing as mp                                                                                                                                

    In [2]: def slow(): 
       ...:     import time; time.sleep(3); print('Done') 
       ...:                                                                                                                                                             

    In [3]: def fast(): 
       ...:     raise Exception('Fast') 

    In [15]: def main(): 
        ...:     import time 
        ...:     s = mp.Process(target=slow) 
        ...:     f = mp.Process(target=fast) 
        ...:     f.start() 
        ...:     s.start() 
        ...:     while s.is_alive() and f.is_alive(): 
        ...:         time.sleep(1) 
        ...:     if s.exitcode or f.exitcode: 
        ...:         s.terminate(); print('s terminated') 
        ...:         f.terminate(); print('f terminated')
```

This attempt is not using `join`, but it seems to get the job done. Is it ok to use?

Comment: Do you want to _join_ the other process, or to _kill_ it? It is not clear from the text. I don't think it is wrong to call `is_alive()` and kill the other, if that is what you need.

Comment: I want both processes to either run together, or die together. So, one dies makes me want to kill the other

Comment: In that case, your code is correct. You should not use `join`, because `join` does not kill anything - quite the opposite, it waits for it to finish.

Comment: [os.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) is exactly what you need, but it is Unix/Linux only.